# All possible combination of remaing items

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

In python using itertools I can use the combinations function to pass in a list and a specified length:

```
results = itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
print (list(results))
```

Result:
 (1,2),

(1,3),

(1,4),

(2,3),

etc..

My question is, how can I do a second set of combinations for a specific length with the **remaining items**

For example, if I want to use the remaining items to do another combination with a length of 2, the results should look like:

(1,2) [(3,4), (3,5), (4,5)]

(1,3) [(2,4), (2,5), (4,5)]

etc...

Comment: Are you trying to get all the combinations of the combinations?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do - which remaining items?  Can you show the code you are using to get you `Result`?

Comment: wwii: I've added complete code with print statement, and formatted the results I'm looking for so its more readable

Comment: Does Andy Carlson's solution below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
import itertools

nums = set(range(1, 6))
for c1 in itertools.combinations(nums, 2):
    c2s = list(itertools.combinations(nums - set(c1), 2))
    print(c1, c2s)
```